# How to make a proper Private class of UiWatcher()

Tags: java, android, automation, android-uiautomator

I am writing a crash code with UiWatcher but my team lead he commented that he needs a "Not an anonymous class. A proper private class." So how can i do that with UiWatcher()

```
private void CrashWatcher() {
    UiWatcher crash = new UiWatcher() {
```

//comment by my lead: Not an anonymous class. A proper private class.

```
            public boolean checkForCondition() {
                UiObject crashButton = new UiObject(
                         new UiSelector().textStartsWith("Unfortunately,"));
            if (crashButton.exists()) {
                log("Found the OK dialog");
                UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector()
                        .className("android.widget.Button").text("OK"));
                try {
                    okButton.click();
                } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                    log("The chance of not having 'OK' button when the application crash is extremely less.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    };

    // Register watcher
    UiDevice.getInstance().registerWatcher(CRASH_WATCHER_NAME, crash);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, extend `UIWatcher` in a named inner class (contained inside your existing classfile/class body):

```
public class MyUIWatcher implements UiWatcher() {
    public boolean checkForCondition() {
    // logic
    }
}
```

and then declare `crash` as:

```
UiWatcher crash = new MyUIWatcher();
```

Comment: error while doing that even i tried to extend it but it gives error.

Comment: Illegal modifier for the local class MyUIWatcher; only abstract or final is permitted

Comment: @Dummycoder Then you're not telling me all the details. Make it an inner class, and instantiate it.

Comment: @Dummycoder This strategy [works for me in a minimal verifiable test](https://ideone.com/kLbUdb).

Comment: @Dummycoder Thati s exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: sorry...it took it in wrong way then...after seeing your example i was able to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class MyUIWatcher implements UiWatcher {
    public boolean checkForCondition() {
        UiObject crashButton = new UiObject(
                new UiSelector().textStartsWith("Unfortunately,"));
        if (crashButton.exists()) {
            log("Found the OK dialog");
            UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(
                    "android.widget.Button").text("OK"));
            try {
                okButton.click();
            } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                log("The chance of not having 'OK' button when the application crash is extremely less.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

};

// Define watcher
private void CrashWatcher() {

    UiWatcher crash = new MyUIWatcher();
    // Register watcher
    UiDevice.getInstance().registerWatcher(CRASH_WATCHER_NAME, crash);
}
```